# Problems creating a Parent Child reference in SSAS

Tags: ssas

In my data warehouse, I have the following dimension that I want to create a Parent Child hierarchy.  My problem is this.  The Primary key is OfficerPeopleID, which is NOT either the parent or child.  The Parent is MgrPeopleID, and the child is PeopleID.
If I change the default key when creating a dimension to PeopleID, it appears as if it will work, but then I receive errors while processing because of it seeing multiple copies of PeopleID.  The reason there are multiples is because it is a SCD type 2 and the Primary Key, (OfficerPeopleID) is the surrogate key for the table.  I know I am not the only one that has tried creating a parent child reference on fields other than the Primary key?
Thank  you!

[image: Dimension]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you would want to do that. If I understand you correctly, PeopleID is your natural key or your source system key and OfficerPeopleID is your DW surrogate key. In this case you would need to have a column which stores the Parent surrogate key not the parent natural key. In other words, you should be able to create a foreign key for the table to itself. Based on what you have right now, you could have more than one record for the manager which would make it ambiguous as to which record is the correct one. Also, for the parent child to work you, the child has to be the key for the table.

If you want to do it properly you should populate the MgrOfficerPoepleID (new column) in your ETL process. If you are going to do that make sure you update the manager key value when you have a new row because of SCD2. However, if you still wish to do it as a named query in SSAS DSV, you can do something like this

```
SELECT        
    OffcerPeopleID,
    -- ... insert other columns here
    PeopleID,
    MgrPeopleID,

    (SELECT OfficerPeopleID
     FROM dbo.Employee
     WHERE(e.MgrPeopleID = PeopleID) AND (IsCurrent = 1)) AS MgrOfficerPoepleID
FROM dbo.OfficerPeopleDim AS e
WHERE IsCurrent = 1 -- this is your SCD2 flag. you could also use two date range columns
```

Comment: Thank you!  I believe the best scenario for me is to do as you said, and have a column that stores the Parent surrogate key.  If you have any suggestions on how i could go about that, i would sure appreciate it!

Comment: I know i can go in and add the column thru the DSV, i am just not sure how to populate it with what would be the Parent Surrogate Key

Comment: Hey John see above for changes

Comment: Thank you!  This is exactly what i needed!  I will give it a try in the morning!  And you are right, i will test it, and then submit it to our ETL team to incorporate into the SSIS etl.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you cant do that if the PeopleID contains duplicate records, either you make it unique or you create the relationship using both fields.

I also advise you to create two separate entries on the DSV, one for Managers and another for Employees, with queries like this:

Manager:

```
select PeopleID as ManagerID, name as Name from OfficerPeopleDim
```

Employee:

```
select PeopleID as EmployeeID, name, MgrPeopleId as Manager
from OfficerPeopleDim
where MgrPeopleId is not null
```

So it will look like this(left) and produce the result on the right:
[image]

Comment: I don't think he can do the above. He needs the surrogate key (OfficerPeopleID) to join to the dimension. Your diagram is missing the surrogate key. Also, in your second query, you will miss the managers themselves which are also employees. He can simply fix the issue by adding the surrogate key for the managers and that would be the true foreign key as I explained below.