# How do i create a Parent surrogate key that corresponds to the Primary surrogate key?

Tags: sql, ssas

I have a table pictured below that has a surrogate Key as the Primary Key, and also two columns that represent a parent child relationship.  Currently, the Primary key is OfficerPeopleID.  The Parent is MgrPeopleID, and the child is PeopleID.
     I want to use the current Primary Key (OfficerPeopleID) as the new child, and create a new field that will be the new parent.  By doing this, the child will now be a primary key, which is my goal.  How do i populate the new parent field to create the same hierarchy structure as the current parent and child fields are doing?
Thank you!

[image: Dimension]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problems creating a Parent Child reference in SSAS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10323189/problems-creating-a-parent-child-reference-in-ssas)

Comment: dont post duplicate questions.

Comment: That was a question of mine, which resulted in me learning this is the next step to fixing my problem.  Thanks

Comment: The question is not a duplicate.  It is my asking help for how to do the next step in resolving the issue i am having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it in your ETL...

```
UPDATE  a
SET     ParentOfficerPeopleID = (   SELECT  OfficerPeopleID 
                                    FROM    OfficerPeopleDim 
                                    WHERE   PeopleID = a.ManagerPeopleID)
FROM    OfficerPeopleDim AS a
```